# Are the conditionals correct

Tags: grammar

Are both 'If he calls you, you should go.' and 'If he called you, you should go.' correct? Is there a difference in meaning between them? Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

The difference between those sentences is the time reference.

For the first one, you're talking about a possibility that might happen in a near future (he might call you).

The second one is referring to an action that happened in the past (he has already called you), so the second statement should also be in a past tense: **you should have gone**.

Comment: Why is the second one referring to an action that has already happened. Isn't past simple used to express present, something that might happen, in this case?

Comment: Past simple can be use for referring to a future situation, but is normally used for situations that are not likely to happen: _if I won the lottery, I would buy a new car_. This is known as the **second conditional**. In your case, the first sentence is referring to a future situation (**first conditional**), and the second would only have a sense if it's referring to a past situation.

Comment: Ok, thank you! So, if that call would be something with virtually no chance to happen, would the sentece 'If he called you, I would be most happy.' make sense? And could I replace that 'would' with 'should', 'If he called you I should be most happy.' or in type two conditionals I can only use 'would'?

Comment: Yes, in that case it would be correct to use a second conditional. And yes, you can also use _should_, _could_ and _might_ in stead of _would_on a second conditional.

Comment: -1: There are ***three*** possibilities here. (1) The call and the going are in the past: *If he called you, you should have gone*. (2) The call and the going are in the future: *If he calls you, you should go.* (3) The call is in the past, and the going is in the future: *If he called you, you should go.* ESL classes that teach there are only three (or four) conditionals are just wrong.

Comment: For the first, where both the call and the going are in the past shouldn't there be 'If he had called you, you should have gone.'?

Comment: My bad. I didn't know that possibility was grammatically correct. I though that mixing a situation from the past and a situation from the future would require a present perfect (_If he has called you, you should go_).

Comment: Is 'If he has called you, you should go.' grammatically correct?

Comment: *"if he has called you, you should go"* is grammatically correct, and probably preferable to *"if he called you, you should go"* unless there's a specific time frame specified (e.g., if the previous sentence contained *"he called me yesterday"*).   They mean essentially the same thing.